# Do I have to get Facebook's permission on the use of their logo for communication purposes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm just a hobbyist programmer and I only distribute free apps. I tried reading the statement on the use of Facebook logo but I get confused by technical statements.

I want to embed a clickable Facebook and Messenger logo in the About section of my app. When the user wants to reach out to me, he/she just need to click the logo.

My question is, do I need permission from Facebook to use their logo for the above-mentioned context? And do I have to post disclaimer or something?

Comment: No, Facebook won't mind if you use their logo for your contact info or Facebook address.

Comment: @HarshGaur thanks a lot. I still have not released the app because I'm afraid I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention one thing, you can only use 'f' logo for this purpose. Not full logo like 'facebook'.  Read this article for more info :  https://smallbusiness.chron.com/add-facebook-logo-marketing-materials-11151.html